# how to specify DocumentFormat for JODConverter 2.2

Tags: java, html, ms-word, doc, jodconverter

I'm willing to use `JODConverter` with `ByteArrayStream` by using the following method.

```
public void convert(InputStream in,
                    DocumentFormat df,
                    OutputStream out,
                    DocumentFormat df1).
```

The problem is i don't know how create a working `DocumentFormat`; what i want is the parameters for .doc(Microsoft Word 2003) and XHTML.

I found something like this but it won't work( I'm using JODConverter 2.2 with OpenOffice 4.0 running on headless mode).

```
DocumentFormat doc = new DocumentFormat("Microsoft Word",
                                        "doc",
                                        "application/msword");
DocumentFormat html = new DocumentFormat("HTML",
                                         "html",
                                         "text/html");
```

it throws the : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported input format: Microsoft Word`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this, this is how you implement a `DocumentFormat` in `JODConverter` 2.2 for `.html` and `.doc` :

```
//for HTML documents.
DocumentFormat html = new DocumentFormat("HTML", DocumentFamily.TEXT, "text/html", "html");
html.setExportFilter(DocumentFamily.TEXT, "HTML (StarWriter)");
//for .doc documents.        
DocumentFormat doc = new DocumentFormat("Microsoft Word", DocumentFamily.TEXT, "application/msword", "doc");
doc.setExportFilter(DocumentFamily.TEXT, "MS Word 97");
```